# refresh of Jquery slider: no such method 'refresh' for slider widget instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I have a many jQuery slider components that I am updating the values of. Each of them has two nobs.

Here is the code that updates the values:

```
this.setState({exceptionsEdit: manual_exceptions}, function(){
    this.state.exceptionsEdit.forEach(function (exp, index){
         var h = $('.exception-list-edit div .slider-range-edit')
         h.each(function(idx, div){

            $(div).slider("values", 0, Date.parse(this.state.exceptionsEdit[idx].start)/1000)
            $(div).slider("values", 1, Date.parse(this.state.exceptionsEdit[idx].end)/1000)
            $(div).slider("refresh")


         }.bind(this))

    }.bind(this))
})
```

The slider values get changed fine, but the slider does not refresh and show the changed value. In fact, `$(div).slider("refresh")` throws an error:

```
jquery.js:250 Uncaught Error: no such method 'refresh' for slider widget instance
```

Why is this happening? How can I refresh these dynamically created/ dynamically changed sliders?

Comment: The library you are using seems to not support such a method.

Comment: Is there an alternative?

Comment: Try calling https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate   to force a rerender

Comment: @Igorsvee I have tried this, it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: found this somewhere on the net `$("#slider").slider("option", "values", values); // this is an ugly workaround, but triggers the change event`

Comment: @Igorsvee can you give a direct code example that pertains to my situation? I don't see how this helps

Comment: Yeah my bad, I should've posted the [link](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7477). And I also suggest using react components like (this one)[https://github.com/react-component/slider] for instance and not rely on stuff that does direct dom manipulations

Comment: Good idea. I just made the switch and it worked smoothly.